# Show value based on id_number

Tags: php, mysql, database, reference

I have 2 table in a database

```
reffQuestion               

ID  QUESTION                  
1   Your pet                  
2   Your fav food              
3   Your hobbies
4   Your fav color
```

```
reffAnswer

IDS ANSWER
1   Cat
2   Pizza
3   Sport
4   Blue
```

It is possible if I write `row["1"];` then it shows the value of `ANSWER`

I wrote:

```
$SQL = "SELECT A.ID from reffQuestion A
        INNER JOIN reffAnswer B on B.IDS = A.ID"

$res = mysql_query($SQL);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $i++;
        $answer[$i] =  $row['answer'];
}
```

Comment: **Please**, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799), and `mysql_*` functions have been officially removed in PHP 7. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. If you can't decide, [this article will help to choose your best option](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Yes, but you need to update your query to retrieve the columns you want to output. Right now, you're only selecting `A.ID`. Try `SELECT *...`

Comment: You are not selecting anything from `reffAnswer` and you didn't use the `semi-colon`at the end of the quey. Try this:

  `$sql   = "  SELECT A.ID, B.* 
    FROM reffQuestion A
        INNER JOIN reffAnswer B on B.IDS = A.ID";`

Comment: @waterloomatt It's generally [not a good idea to use the `*` selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Sorry you need to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp.  And http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php.  mysql_ is a NONO.

Comment: thank you very much for all you guys...its very helpful..